# How to set parameters in auto-closable resources when the result set has parameters?

Tags: java, jdbc

What is the correct way to do a try-with-resources connection -> statement -> resultset with parameters. If I have

```
    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from foo where bar = ?");
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery()) {
        while (result.next()) {
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    }
```

I can't set the parameter inside the try-block. I can however do the stuff in an external function like `PreparedStatement statement = getStatement(connection, parameter)` but does this have any side-effects in the auto-closing or does the try-with-resources still keep track of everything even if connection.createStatement happens "externally"?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to nest try-with-resources. Like this:

```
try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
     PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from foo where bar = ?");
    statement.setString(1, "baz);
    try (ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery()) {
        // etc
    }
}
```

Well-behaving JDBC drivers will automatically close statements when the connection closes, and result sets when the statement closes, but it is better to always program defensive and ensure resources are always closed properly.

Try-with-resources is not specific to JDBC. What a try-with-resources basically does, is tack on a `finally` block that closes the resources in the proper order by calling their `close()` methods. As a result, try-with-resources doesn't care where the resource is coming from as long as it implements `AutoCloseable`. It just ensures that `close()` is called on a resource at the end of the block. So it doesn't care if *"connection.createStatement happens "externally""*. The method `createStatement` is just another method that returns a resource, and try-with-resources is only concerned with the object returned.